# Angular.js > how to manage configuration

Tags: php, angularjs

I got stuck with passing a configuration to our angular application. My problem is

1. We have configuration is stored in database, so far it's URL of web service to communicate with
2. Page is rendered by PHP

How can I pass URL stored in database to ng-app?

So far I have hard-coded services.js

```
app.constant('config', {ws_url: 'ws://domain/ws'});

app.factory('wampy', function ($rootScope, config) {

  var url =  config.ws_url;
  var ws = new Wampy(url, { autoReconnect: true });

  return {
    something: function () {
        console.log(url);   // usage of url
    }
  }

}
```

Then it is included into main html code (index.php)

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.local/js/ng/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.local/js/ng/services.js"></script>
</head>
```

But it can be amended / moved to somewhere else.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a snippet of javascript rendered by php into a script tag like so

```
$config = array('ws_url' => 'ws://domain/ws');
$jsonConfig = json_encode($config);

$snippet = <<<EOS
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('appName').constant('config', $jsonConfig);
    </script>
EOS;
```

and then output this `$snippet` somewhere in your page.